# Subgroups of p-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a (non-abelian) $p$-group, $|G|=p^n$, $n>3$, then it is elementary that $G$ contains a (normal) abelian subgroup of order $p^2$. It is also true that $G$ necessarily contains a **normal abelian subgroup** of order $p^3$ (*Group Theory - W. R. Scott*).

**1)** What is the largest possible value of $m$ such that **any** non-abelian group of order $p^n$ contains a **normal abelian subgroup** of order $p^m$?

**2)** What is the largest possible value of $m$ such that **any** non-abelian group of order $p^n$ contains an **abelian subgroup** of order $p^m$?

[Please suggest references.]

Comment: Here are some suggested references: G A Miller, On the number of abelian subgroups.. in Messenger Math 36 (1906/7).  SC Dancs, Abelian subgroups of finite $p$-groups in Trans AMS 169 (1972).  Miller shows a group of order $p^n$ has a normal abelian subgroup of order $p^m$ where $m(m+1)/2 \geq n$.

Comment: @mt, your comment should be an answer (after you correct the inequality).

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=-EkNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA120&dq=dickson+group+theory&hl=en&ei=uG1uTY-fH4L48AbjvcjqDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=4&ved=0CD0Q6wEwAw#v=onepage&f=false

Comment: should be tagged p-groups 

Answer (score 6):

I've been asked to post the following as an answer, although it does not answer either of your questions (i.e. it does not provide the largest $m$).

Here are some suggested references: G A Miller, On the number of abelian subgroups.. in Messenger Math 36 (1906/7). [SC Dancs, Abelian subgroups of finite $p$-groups in Trans AMS 169 (1972)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1996255). Miller shows a group of order $p^n$ has a normal abelian subgroup of order $p^m$ for some $m$ such that $m (m+1)/2 \geq n$.  The inequality is correct.  Huppert's Endliche Gruppen book is cited there as an alternative proof of Miller's paper (what I remember of that paper is that it is very hard to read).

Edit: a better reference is Zassenhaus's book `The Theory of Groups', IV.3.4.  There you find a simple argument for the lower bound above.  It's clear from his proof that the lower bound can be improved if you have control of the number of generators of a maximal normal abelian subgroup, for example in the case that the big group is regular.

Comment: G. A. Miller has lots of amazing results, and a quite unique writing style. I is always nice to get an excuse to read him :)

Answer (score 3):

George Glauberman and also Jon Alperin and George Glauberman together have written papers
on this topic in recent years. One example is: "A note on abelian subgroups of p-groups."
Groups St. Andrews 2005. Vol. 2, 445–447, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 340, Cambridge
Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2007.

Comment: Yakov Berkovich also has a series of papers on subgroups of finite $p$-groups. For example:

Y. Berkovich, On abelian subgroups of $p$-groups, J. Algebra 199 (1998), 262--280.



Answer (score 2):

A. Yu. Olshanskii [proved in 1978](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=8148&option_lang=eng)
that, for any $n$ and any prime $p$, 
there exists a $p$-group of order at least 
$
p^{{1\over 8}(n^2+4n-8)}
$
having no abelian subgroups of order large than $p^n$.
Together with Miller's estimate $p^{{1\over2}n(n+1)}$ (see @m_t's answer), this gives quadratic upper and lower bounds.

---

Similar questions for commutative subalgebras in (associative and Lie) algebras was [studied by M.V.Milentyeva](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=fpm&paperid=940&option_lang=eng). The estimates are also quadratic in this case.